# How to merge .txt files in subfolders and name them after in the same way as the main folder using R?

Tags: r, merge, directory, naming, subdirectory

I have performed an experiment under different conditions. Each of those condition has its own Folder. In each of those folders, there is a subfolder for each replicate that containts a text file called DistList.txt. This then looks like this, where the folders "C1.1", "C1.2" and so on contain the mentioned .txt files:

[image]

Those .txt files then look like this, but their length may vary from only one or two to several hundreds:

[image]

Now, I would like to merge those .txt files and create a .csv file out of it in a way that it looks like this:

```
C1.1  C1.2  C1.3  ...
155   223   996
169   559   999
259   623   1033
2003        2220
4421
```

Until now, I was able to write a script that takes together all the files and plots the single data in different columns, just as I want it. However, I would like the title of each column to be the name of the main folder I extracted the .txt file of (e.g. C1.1, C1.2, C1.3, C2.1, ...).

So far, I have this script:

```
fileList <- list.files(path = ".", recursive = TRUE, pattern = "DistList.txt", full.names = TRUE)

listData <- lapply(fileList, read.table)

names(listData) <- gsub("DistList.txt","",basename(fileList))

library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

bind_rows(listData, .id = "FileName") %>%
  group_by(FileName) %>%
  mutate(rowNum = row_number()) %>%
  dcast(rowNum~FileName, value.var = "V1") %>%
  select(-rowNum) %>%
  write.csv(file="Result.csv")
```

This then yields a .csv file like this, where there are just numbers as column headers and not the name I would like to have. This is an extract of the file created, where I have marked the row that should contain the titles as mentioned above (C1.1, C1.2, C1.2, ...):

[image]

Is there any possibility to name the columns as I have mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the line :

```
names(listData) <- gsub("DistList.txt","",basename(fileList))
```

has to be replaced by

```
names(listData) <- basename(dirname(fileList))
```

so that the the names of the subfolders are used as the headers of the single columns.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstood, but why not do this

```
# Generate some sample data consisting of a list
# of single-column data.frame's
set.seed(2017);
listData <- list(
    C1 = data.frame(V1 = runif(10)),
    C2 = data.frame(V1 = runif(10)),
    C3 = data.frame(V1 = runif(10)))

setNames(bind_cols(listData), names(listData))
#           C1          C2         C3
#1  0.92424261 0.674331481 0.63411352
#2  0.53717641 0.002020766 0.37986744
#3  0.46919565 0.025093514 0.94207403
#4  0.28862618 0.432077786 0.75499369
#5  0.77008816 0.499391912 0.22761184
#6  0.77276871 0.388681932 0.91466603
#7  0.03932234 0.395375316 0.62044504
#8  0.43490560 0.715707325 0.31910458
#9  0.47216639 0.940999879 0.07628881
#10 0.27383312 0.827229161 0.26083932
```

Explanation: We simply bind the single column of all `data.frame`s in `listData` and set column names with `setNames`.

I don't understand why you're doing a `bind_rows` first, and then later recast from long to wide. The same can be achieved with a single `bind_cols`.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't really help, as I would like to list the single .txt files one besides each other and I don't want to type every single Name. Is there no function to copy the name of the folder the file is in?

Comment: @Marc I have to say I completely don't understand your issue. In my example I'm *not* manually setting every name; names get passed on from `listData` to the columns of the combined `data.frame`. The function that does that is `setNames`; this starts to sound like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Can you edit your question to include some sample/fake data (similar to what I did) but representative of your case, and also your expected output for that particular case (the `data.frame`); perhaps then things will become clearer.

Comment: I have now added the additional information as well as a picture of the .csv file that I have created.